Get error when I use go get command with private package
(Since my account level is not enough to send pictures, I posted my issue address)：issue
Below content is describe the problem briefly.
I done below steps before go get private package:
Step1: set go_private_proxy use code.xxx.com.
Step2: set git insteadOf---
[url "git@172.18.x.x:"]
        insteadOf = https://code.xxx.com/

My private repo on gitea like:
git:  git@172.18.x.x:common/ts_utils.git

After I done these steps. I'm use go get  at another repo import utils repo into my project.
I use go get -u code.xxx.com/common/ts_utils command import utils private package into my other repo. But I get err:
Also I'm try to use go get -v code.teamsun.com/common/ts_utils.git(extra suffix: .git)
I think i need to add utils project go.mod:
I am not sure why such an error occurs  with go get to my private package.
I tried something else：

remove utils go.mod. go get -u xxx/xxx/utils.git(But I need go.mod file)
use replace in import repo go.mod file.

But I need manual to upgrade private pkg when utils code update .
These are some intermediate steps that can be ignored because I don't want the real problem to get lost.
Thank you all in advance for your help.
